# Какой знак нужен перед "рекламщиками"? Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Показать бы тебя нашим спецам рекламщикам, к примеру.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Показать бы тебя нашим спецам, **рекламщикам  к примеру**.*

Вводное слово (сочетание) не отделяется знаком препинания от обособленного оборота, если находится в самом начале или **в самом конце предложения:** По-видимому опасаясь снежных заносов, руководитель группы отменил восхождение на вершину горы; Оставьте вы эти новые доводы, **неубедительные и надуманные конечно.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пояснение

1) Слово ***спец*** (без зависимых слов) ближе к сленговым выражениям (согласно словарю).

**СПЕЦ**, м. 1. **В первые годы Советской власти**: опытный специалист, выходец из непролетарской среды. 2. на что, в чём, по чему и с инф. Разг. Тот, кто умеет хорошо делать что-л., мастер, знаток в каком-л. деле. С. в этом деле. С. по автомобилям. С. на выдумки. С. плясать.

2) Нет выражения ***спецы рекламщики***, в том числе и при дефисном написании.

3) Особых оснований для употребления тире в этом предложении нет, запятой вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

О! Возможны варианты.

1. Не ставить НИЧЕГО. Оставить как есть. Счесть "спецов" приложением.
2. Поставить запятую перед "рекламщикам", зато убрать перед "к примеру":

*Показать бы тебя нашим спецам, рекламщикам к примеру.*

3. То же, что (2), но с тире:

*Показать бы тебя нашим спецам — рекламщикам к примеру.*